# How to correct this apex method?

Tags: apex, visualforce

> I have created a apex method to get Lead record based on current page lead Id    > and update a field on lead. below is the apex method.I am getting an error 
>    "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

```
Public Void addtolead() {

Lead Ld = [select Id,name,Unit__c from Lead where Id= :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
  Ld.Unit__c = 'R-100';
  update Ld;
}
```

Kindly let me know how to Update Lookupfield "Unit__c" on Lead.below is the method. The lookupfield "Unit__c" is related to custom Object "Condo__c".

```
  Public Pagereference addtolead() {
  Unitnamevf=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('UnitNameParam');
   LeadRecordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
   List<Lead> Lds = new List<Lead>([select Id,Unit__c from Lead where Id= :LeadRecordId]);
 if(!Lds.isEmpty()) 
    {
      Lds[0].Unit__c = Unitnamevf; 
      update Lds[0];
        }

refreshPage=true;  
return null;
}
```

Comment: Review these questions/answers http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=List+has+no+rows+for+assignment+to+SObject.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that salesforce does not find any records in the database. Probably because of your `id` is either `null` or not found.

You can fix this by doing this:

```
List<Lead> Lds = new List<Lead>([select Id,name,Unit__c from Lead where Id= :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')]);

if(!Lds.isEmpty()) {
  Lds[0].Unit__c = 'R-100'; // this needs to be a Unit__c record id. 'R-100 is not a record id.
  update Ld[0];
}
```

Comment: The field Unit__c is a lookup Field to other Object.

Comment: I have tried the above code.but it is not updating the Unit Field in lead with the value.

Comment: Then you need to add a Unit__c record id  to Lds[0].Unit__c. 'R-100' is not a record id.

Comment: can you show a sample how to write it?

Comment: Since Lead.Unit__c is a lookup field you need an actual Unit__c object. Either create a new one and save it or fetch one from the Database. Then assign the `id (Unit__c.Id) to Lead.Unit__c`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion.but not able to find the solution.i have added the updated method.kindly take a look and let me know how to correct it.